# How can i get my form to resize based on the user's screen resolution, and also have the picture inside the picturebox scale with it?

Tags: c#

I feel like i've tried everything to no avail. I have been trying to resize my form1 based on the user's screen resolution. I also want to resize the picturebox inside the form (and also the background image within it)

So i started with this

```
int sizeChange = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size.Height - Size.Height
```

this should get the difference between the current picture size and the actual resolution

```
Height += sizeChange;
Width += sizeChange;
canvas.Height += sizeChange;
canvas.Width += sizeChange;
```

Then, with this i am trying to modify the size of the form and height based on the size difference in form size and screen resolution. Am i going about this all wrong? I've been trying different things all week (this is most recent solution) and feel like nothing is working.

Comment: it should be possible to compute the final dimensions of the picturebox directly in absolute values, without tracking a delta. could you disclose more of your project, like is it WPF, or windows forms, and relevant parts of the control interaction code?

Comment: @dlatikay yeah i can do that! Its a windows form application. What exactly do you need to see from the control interaction code?

Comment: just confirmation that `Height` is the client height of the form that contains the picturebox, and `canvas` is the picturebox. then you could use to onresize event of the form to set canvas.Width=Width-padding. etc.

Comment: Did you try to set AutoScaleMode to Dpi? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @dlatikay yes both of those statements are correct. I want the form to automatically size on runtime to be the proper size for whatever the users screen resolution is.

Comment: @LucianBumb Yes, that makes it so the image scales, it doesen't allow the form to change size on runtime tho.